# How to use trim and if condition in ansible playbook?

Tags: ansible

I am writing a interface clean-up playbook for Cisco router. Need to do some pre-checks like

Show process cpu - run this and if the output is if cpu utilization is more than 80%, Then i need to skip the playbook

```
- hosts: Switch
  connection: local
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: run show version on remote devices
    ios_command:
      commands:
        - show version
        - show interfaces
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use task with [*fail* module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/fail_module.html) and [*when* condition](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#the-when-statement).

In the condition you should compare your CPU load threshold value with current CPU load obtained from facts (e.g. [*ios_facts* module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ios_facts_module.html)).

If there is no such value in facts, you should get current load in previous task and pass it as registered variable as shown [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#register-variables).